# Composition API arrow function is not recognized in Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I am using the Nuxt Composition API and trying to render the elements in getList to my page. When I load the page I get an error saying that "_vm.getList is not a function".

```
 <template>
  <div class="drop-zone">
    <div v-for="item in getList(1)" :key="item.id" class="drag-el">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>   
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    setup(){
      const items = ref([
        {id:0, title: 'Item A', list:1},
        {id:1, title: 'Item B', list:1},
        {id:2, title: 'Item C', list:2},
      ]),

      const getList = (list) => {
        return items.value.filter((item) => item.list == list);
      },

      return {
        getList,
    }
  },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason for a property to not exist in the instance is that there are other errors in the component, e.g. what the answer suggests. Another one is that you use old framework version that is unaware of  `setup`. Debug your code to make sure that `return` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ref` (not sure how), then this one should work

```html
<template>
  <div class="drop-zone">
    <div v-for="item in getList(1)" :key="item.id" class="drag-el">
      {{ item.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const items = ref([
      { id: 0, title: 'Item A', list: 1 },
      { id: 1, title: 'Item B', list: 1 },
      { id: 2, title: 'Item C', list: 2 },
    ])

    const getList = (list) => {
      return items.value.filter((item) => item.list === list)
    }

    return {
      getList,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

At least, ESlint is not complaining with this. Sorry if I can't help more, didn't worked with Vue3 so far (yet).

Comment: I had added the following: import { ref } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api' and it still doesn't work. I get the same error

Comment: There were some minor issues with your template too. Did you tried mine or turned on ESlint?

Comment: I used your version of the code. I still have the same error about the getList function

Comment: Maybe you need to define it as a function, idk. Sorry, cannot help more here.

Comment: @el_M There seems to be no `ref` in '@nuxtjs/composition-api' . You need to import it correctly any way because otherwise you use a function that is not defined in this component.

Comment: `ref` seems to be available in the nuxt module: https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/lifecycle/useFetch

Comment: @kissu yes I had seen it in the documentation too